# How can I bind keys dynamically in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, onkeyup

How can I bind keys dynamically?
In a larger application, an input component should be addressed using different key combinations.

Example:

Page 1, Mask 1: input with @keyup. 13
Page 1, Mask 2: input with @keyup. 112

Several combinations may be necessary for each input.
Any ideas to make this scalable and clean?

(There are well over 500 input fields)

Comment: You can bind attribute to input, then bind keyup event to all input. Then detect input and check keyup combination.

Comment: thanks. Found v-hotkey instead, sounds like a god solution.